# Bootstrap, break a column out the container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want two `col-*-6` in one `.row`. The left `col` has a `background-color` which has to go all the way to the left border of the screen. Also there is text in the first `col`, which has to be aligned with the normal `.container` with. The right `col` has a `background-image` which has to go all the way to the right border of the screen.

[here is a image example of I want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KrUW.png)
This is the current code that I have, without all the unnecessary elements:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-6 text">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, sed do lorem ipsum.</h2>
    </div> <!-- close col-md-6 text -->
    <div class="col-md-6 image" id="slided01">
    </div> <!-- close col-md-6 image -->
  </div> <!-- close row -->
</div><!-- close container-fluid -->
```

The problem with the above code is that the text is aligned to the left side of the screen, because of the `.container-fluid`. And I want the text to be aligned with the normal `.container` width.

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7xcfq6e/4/). The first row is how I want the background to be, the second row is how I want the text to be.

Comment: Please provide your fiddle. The image you have attached is what you desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could absolute position the `container-fluid` under the `container`, and use CSS to keep the heights of both containers the same.

```
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/pLKx5nEZF6

Answer (score 8):

try this (it is not the most compatible code on the planet, but it is CSS solution /no JS/)

```
.break-container{
  width:100vw;
  position:relative;
  left:calc(-1 * (100vw - 100%)/2);
}
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/vencedor/aq9Laaew/24452/](https://www.codeply.com/go/pLKx5nEZF6)

Comment: This works! I keep wondering _how_ it works though. `100vw` gives you the entire width. Then you're subtracting `100%` of the width of the element itself, divided by two (is that to get the widths of outside the container?

Comment: this works brilliantly and should be the accepted answer